# How to enable suspend mode on a Windows Server 2008 R2 box?

Tags: electrical-power, windows, wake-on-lan

I want to use Wake-On-LAN for my two office machines, both of which run Windows 2008 Server R2 (for Hyper-V), but it seems the Server SKU doesn't offer a suspend option anyway.

I'm sure it's just a registry key or something. How can I enable my servers to sleep?

Answer (score 1):

Sleep is not supported on Server 2008 R2 when the Hyper-V role is installed: http://blogs.technet.com/b/doxley/archive/2008/02/13/insomnia-causing-hyper-v.aspx